# Google Apps Script for sending email contains multiple rows data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a data similar to this one

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HS7r.png)

I want to send emails from the appscript.

The logic to send email as follows.

Only send 1 email to each unique value in Column A (Co Name) the content of the email will include data in all rows. Only send email where Column N value is "Y". For example,

The script will only send 3 emails:

Email 1:
This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 1" has expired.

- Mr A - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021
- Mr B - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

Email 2:
This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 4" has expired.

- Mr C - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

Email 3:
This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 5" has expired.

- Mr D - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

I use this script. However, it cannot send email that contains multiple rows data. It send 4 emails instead of 3. Please help me. Thank you.

```
function HLReminderAtYE(){
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //declare the spreadsheet
var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Tax_Master");  //declare sheet name
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange(); //to set the range as array
var Values = Range.getDisplayValues(); //to get the value in the array  

let fvs = Values.filter(function (item) { return item[13] == "Y" }); // filter only housecontract to remind at year end
  
var templateText = SS.getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();

fvs.forEach(function(row){
    
  var AssigneeNames = row[1];
  var ClientNames = row[0];
  var HLEndDates = row[7];
  var messageBody = templateText.replace("{ClientNames}",ClientNames).replace("{AssigneeNames}",AssigneeNames).replace("{HouseleaseEndDates}",HLEndDates);
    
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    row[12],          // email address
    row[0] + "- House lease contract expire", // Subject line
    messageBody);
  });
}
```

Comment: @Cooper are you here? :)

Comment: Your loop iterates over every row that has the reminder flag set. You have 4 rows, resulting in 4 emails. You should first collect all unique "Co names" in an array, iterate over that array and find the correspoding rows for the current "co name" and put it into an email.

Comment: Use an object to create properties for each assignee or client which ever you wish and collect and array of rows for each key along with a property arrays that lists all of the properties as an array.  When you have completed your collection you can iterate through your property array to send single emails to assignees or clients as you have chosen previously.  I use the Object.hasOwnProperty() method to determine if the property has already been created or not.  It's the same idea as creating pivot or reverse pivot tables.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. Aerials's answer is the solution for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following sample table of leases with the headers being:

["owner","leaser","owner's email address","Y/N"]

[image: sample data sheet]

to show you the idea.

The following example shows how to group the "Y" leases by "owner" and only send one email to the "owner's email address" with all the "leaser" that expired (those rows with "Y").

#### Example:

```js
function HLReminderAtYE() {
    let SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare the spreadsheet
    let Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //declare sheet name
    let Range = Sheet.getDataRange(); //to set the range as array
    let Values = Range.getDisplayValues(); //to get the value in the array  

    // Get all rows with a "Y" to send email
    let fvs = Values.filter((item) => {
        if (item[3] == "Y") return item
    });
    // Create an object grouped by owner
    fvs = fvs.map(
        (row) => {
            return {
                'name': row[0],
                'data': row.slice(1, 3)
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(fvs);
    fvs = fvs.reduce((r, a) => {
        r[a.name] = r[a.name] || [];
        r[a.name].push(a.data);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    let templateText = "{ClientNames} House lease contract expired.\n";

    Object.keys(fvs).forEach((key) => {
        let messageBody = ''
        fvs[key].forEach((row) => {
            let ClientNames = row[0];
            messageBody += templateText.replace("{ClientNames}", ClientNames);
        });


        // Send email
        MailApp.sendEmail(
            fvs[key][0][1], // owner's email address
            "House leases contract expired", // Subject line
            messageBody);

    });
}
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)