# Apps Script: Send email - Script sends 1 email per row instead of one email with all the info that meets the criteria

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Newbie looking for some help... I can't understand what is going wrong in this script!

I am using a sheet [similar to this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RdQJX_7yEjuRfQ-qKQoNtRAywKCEr4uYw21ss0f-J-k/edit?usp=sharing). My objective is to send and email to a specific address whenever certain conditions are met.

The conditions are Col R (Yesterday = 1) & Col D (Status) is different than "Resgate".

This is the output I am getting from my script. If 2 rows meet these conditions, then I get an email with the first row that meets conditions, and then another email with the first and second row that meets conditions. If there where 5 rows that meet conditions, I would receive 5 emails, and in the last one, I would have all the rows that meet conditions.

What I want to achieve is to receive only the final email with all the rows that meet conditions and avoid receiving the other ones.

**Email 1**

[image: This is Email 1]

**Email 2**
[image: This is Email 2]

**This Is the code I am using**

```js
function SENDMAIL() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // set active sheet to Sheet by name
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"));
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    // figure out what the last row is
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var startRow = 2;
    // grab all data from user to days left
    var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 19);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var users1 = [];
    var users2 = [];
    var users3 = [];
    var users4 = [];
    var users5 = [];
    var users6 = [];

    // loop all data per row
    values.forEach(function(row) {
        if (row[17] == 1 && row[3] !== "Resgate") {
            // add user if 4 or more days left
            users1.push(row[3]);
            users2.push(row[4]);
            users3.push(row[5]);
            users4.push(row[16]);
            users5.push(row[15]);
            users6.push(row[14]);
            // if users has elements
            var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>New Requests</font2></h1>";
            var names = "<ul>";
            users4.forEach(function(user, i) {
                names += `<p><b><li>${user} -> ${users1[i]} - ${users3[i]} - ${users2[i]} - ${users5[i]} - ${users6[i]}€ `;
            });
            names += "</ol>"
            message = message + names + "</body></html>";
            var flexmails = "Example@gmail.com";
            MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "NEW PPR's", "", {
                htmlBody: message,
                noReply: true
            });
        } else {}
    })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68560635/4243927

Comment: It does not :( 
The problem is not repeating the same user, it is that I am sending a new email for any new row that meets the criteria..
Can't seem to get the sendEmail out from the values.forEach loop and put it at the end of the script...

Comment: Can you comment with more details your code line by line to explain what you are trying to do in every step?And show what a row of your spreadsheet looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move `sendEmail` out from the `values.forEach` loop and put it at the end of the script

```js
MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "NEW PPR's","", { htmlBody: message, noReply: true });
```

---

```js
    values.forEach(function(row) {
        if (row[17] == 1 && row[3] !== "Resgate") {
            // add user if 4 or more days left
            users1.push(row[3]);
            users2.push(row[4]);
            users3.push(row[5]);
            users4.push(row[16]);
            users5.push(row[15]);
            users6.push(row[14]);
        }
    });


            // if users has elements
            var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>New Requests</font2></h1>";
            var names = "<ul>";
            users4.forEach(function(user, i) {
                names += `<p><b><li>${user} -> ${users1[i]} - ${users3[i]} - ${users2[i]} - ${users5[i]} - ${users6[i]}€ `;
            });
            names += "</ol>"
            message = message + names + "</body></html>";
            var flexmails = "Example@gmail.com";
            MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "NEW PPR's", "", {
                htmlBody: message,
                noReply: true
            });
```

Comment: I am not able to take it out of the valyes.foreach loop... When I do, an error occurs saying that the else (from the if function) is misplaced... ‍♂️

Comment: I cannot understand what are you talking about and what you are trying to do exactly. You are looping E2 1 time, E3 2 times, E4 3 times, ...

Comment: I have added the revised code which I guess it is what you intend to do.